# Get data of selected node in antd tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I want to get underlying data, of **selected node** in antd [tree](https://ant.design/components/tree/).

This is sample tree data (just one node):

```
let treeData =[{title: "0-0",
            key: "0-0",
            children: []}];
```

Tree has onSelect with such signature:

```
onSelect = (selectedKeys, info) => {

};
```

`info.node.getNodeState()` gives me such result when I select node:

[image]

You can see the `title` is a **react element**. Instead I wanted just the underlying value of `title` element, that is: `"0-0"`.

Is there no way to access the selected nodes underlying data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 
`info.selectedNodes[0].props` to access the nodes data. Or if you pass the data in as prop like -

```
<TreeNode title={item.title} key={item.key} dataRef={item}>
    {this.renderTreeNodes(item.children)}
</TreeNode>
```

then you can also get the data in `info.selectedNodes[0].props.dataRef`